# How can I create an array with quotes around each item when the parameter also needs quotes around it?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to select multiple items on OLAP Slicers with VBA.

And example of a literal command to do this would be:

```
ThisWorkBook.SlicerCaches("Some_Slicer_Cache").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _
"[D_MUMAP].[MU_ID].&[item1]", "[D_MUMAP].[MU_ID].&[item2]")
```

I'm pulling "items" from a comma delimited list (in another cell)

```
item1, item2
```

And processing them into an array and outputting the entire string to another cell (Not really necessary I guess but I like having the visual).

```
[D_MUMAP].[MU_ID].&[item1], [D_MUMAP].[MU_ID].&[item2]
```

**This array process works when there's only one item**, obviously because the only set of quotes is already implied. If I try to run it with multiple, I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '1004':
The query did not run or the Data Model could not be accessed.
Query (1,25) The syntax for ',' is incorrect.
([D_MUMAP].[MU_ID].&[item1], [D_MUMAP].[MU_ID].&[item2]).
```

What next steps should I try to solve this?

Comment: What is the code you have already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following will work in which case you don't need to deal with double-quotes at all:

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim list As String
    'the input list of items
    list = "item1,item2,item3"

    'split this into an array
    Dim listArray
    listArray = Split(list, ",")

    'for each element, prepend [D_MUMAP].[MU_ID].&[ and append ]
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(listArray)
        listArray(i) = "[D_MUMAP].[MU_ID].&[" & listArray(i) & "]"
    Next i

    'dump array for interest's sake
    Debug.Print Join(listArray, ", ")

    'update slicer
    ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Some_Slicer_Cache").VisibleSlicerItemsList = listArray
End Sub
```

Comment: i thought my splitting sub did exactly this but I must have fudged up somewhere. thank you!